# A normalized outer product matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

We are given a vector $z$ and a matrix $A$. We know that $C = AA^T$ and C is a symmetric, positive definite matrix.

Furthermore we are given the equation: 
$R = \frac{1}{z^Tz} Az(Az)^T$

What can we say about the new matrix $R$ (Eigenvectors, Eigenvalues, trace etc.)? How does the first part of the term $\frac{1}{z^Tz}$ relate to second one $Az(Az)^T$ and to $R$? Is it possible to express $R$ in terms of $C$?

In my understanding $\frac{1}{z^Tz}$ is some kind of normalization factor, bringing the vectors $z$ to unit length.

Answer (score 1):

Define the vectors
$$\eqalign{
u &= \frac{z}{\|z\|},\quad x=Au\in{\mathbb R}^n\\
}$$
Then $R = xx^T$ is a rank-one matrix and therefore has only ***one*** non-zero eigenvalue, which is simple to calculate.
$$Rx = xx^Tx = \lambda x \quad\implies\lambda = x^Tx = \frac{z^TA^TAz}{z^Tz}$$
The other $(n-1)$ eigenvalues equal zero, and the corresponding eigenvectors are

any set of $(n-1)$ linearly independent vectors which are *orthogonal* to $x$.